# Optimization Problem about total variation in the distribution parameter's neighborhood

Tags: probability-theory, optimization, total-variation

Given two fixed distribution as $p_\theta,p_{\theta^*}$. In the neighborhood of $\theta$, there exists a small region $\epsilon$, which forms the distribution $p_{\theta+\epsilon}$.

These three distributions meets the following conditions:

$D_{TV}(p_\theta||p_{\theta+\epsilon}) + D_{TV}(p_{\theta+\epsilon}|| p_{\theta^*}) \ge D_{TV}(p_\theta || p_{\theta^*})$

I would like to solve the following optimization problem :

$\arg \max_\epsilon D_{TV}(p_\theta||p_{\theta+\epsilon}) + D_{TV}(p_{\theta+\epsilon}|| p_{\theta^*}) - D_{TV}(p_\theta || p_{\theta^*}) $

How could I do ? Any information would be appreciate for me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total variation distance is not generally easy to differentiate with respect to distribution parameters, and the expressions for $p_θ$, $p_{θ+ε}$, and $p_{θ^*}$ are not given in your question. Additionally, the total variation distance has a triangle inequality property, which makes it challenging to solve this optimization problem analytically. You can approach this problem using numerical methods or optimization techniques, such as gradient-based optimization or stochastic optimization algorithms (e.g., stochastic gradient descent or a genetic algorithm), depending on the specific functional forms of the distributions and their parameters. I need more information about the specific distributions you are working with and any constraints on $ε$ to help you further.

**Updated**
In the case of Gaussian distributions, the total variation distance have no closed-form expression. Let's assume $p_θ$, $p_{θ^*}$, and $p_{θ+ε}$ are all Gaussian distributions with means $μ_θ$, $μ_{θ^*}$, and $μ_{θ+ε}$ and variances $σ^2_θ$, $σ^2_{θ^*}$, and $σ^2_{θ+ε}$, respectively.

The total variation distance between two Gaussian distributions p and q with means $μ_p$, $μ_q$ and variances $σ^2_p$, $σ^2_q$ is given by:

$ D_{TV}(p || q) = 1/2 ∫ |p(x) - q(x)| dx$

The derivative of the total variation distance between Gaussian distributions with respect to their means and variances does not have a simple closed-form expression.

In your case, since $ε$ is a small perturbation and the update rule is based on gradient descent, it may be more practical to perform numerical optimization or use a gradient-based approach for estimating the optimal $ε$. You can estimate the gradients using finite differences or automatic differentiation libraries, and then update the parameters iteratively.

Keep in mind that the optimization problem might not have a unique solution or might be sensitive to the choice of the initial $ε$ value. However, by carefully selecting the step size and the optimization algorithm, you can still find a good approximation for the optimal $ε$ value.

Comment: the distribution here is the Gaussian Distribution, and the $\epsilon$ can not be so large, which is just  a perturbation. @rumathe

Comment: the $\theta+\epsilon$ could be seen as the updation from $\theta$ by gradient descent @rumathe

Comment: does the function $D_{TV}(\cdot)$  has derivative ? @rumathe

Comment: @11, updated answer

Comment: in your answer, the CDF means use $u_p-u_q$ as expectation and $\sigma_p^2+\sigma_q^2$ as variance ? I'm a little confused.

Comment: @11, apologize for the confusion I made an error in expression.

Comment: could you please tell me how can I get that closed form @rumathe

Comment: To find the optimal $ε$, you need to differentiate the $Objective(ε)$ function with respect to $ε$ and set the result to zero. If you rewrite $D_{TV}(p||q)$ as $D_{TV}(p||q) = \frac{1}{4} erfc(\frac{|μ_p - μ_q|}{2 \sqrt{2 (σ^2_p + σ^2_q)}} )$. But it's still challenging and not practical to find an explicit closed-form solution.

Comment: could you please tell me why $D_{TV}(p||q) = {1\above{1pt}2}|\Phi(u_p/\sigma_p)-\Phi(u_q/\sigma_q)|$ @rumathe

Comment: @11 I confused myself, I've updated answer. The argument for $Φ$ is the difference between the means of $p$ and $q$, $μ_p - μ_q$, divided by the square root of the sum of their variances, $\sqrt{σ^2_p + σ^2_q}$. The total variation distance is calculated by evaluating $Φ$ at this value. Note that Φ takes a scalar argument, not an expectation and variance. The expression $\frac{μ_p - μ_q}{\sqrt{σ^2_p + σ^2_q}}$ is the standardized difference between the means of the two Gaussian distributions, which is used as the argument for $Φ$.

Comment: the TV, as I know, is defined by $D_{TV}={1\above{1pt}2}\sum |p-q|$ ,why for Gaussian distribution can be traverted to $\Phi({u_p-u_q\above{1pt}\sqrt{\sigma_p^2-\sigma_q^2}})  $? Could you please show me the induction process ?

Comment: The total variation distance between two probability distributions p and q is defined as:  $D_{TV}(p || q) = 1/2 ∑ |p(x) - q(x)|$. For continuous distributions, the summation becomes an integral: $D_{TV}(p || q) = 1/2 ∫ |p(x) - q(x)| dx$

Comment: yep, but why the integral term can be traverted to $\Phi({u_p-u_q\above{1pt}\sqrt{\sigma_p^2-\sigma_q^2}})  $ @rumathe

Comment: I think I misunderstood your problem. It actually cannot. And there's no simple closed-form for it. There are special cases.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022849/total-variation-distance-of-two-centered-normal-distributions  
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156946/are-there-known-expressions-for-total-variation-distance-between-n0-sigma-12  
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.08693

Comment: I just confused about the statement in your answer  "The total variation distance between two Gaussian distributions p and q with means $μ_p, μ_q$ and variances $σ^2_p, σ^2_q $ is given by: $D_{TV}(p||q) = \Phi(u_p-u_q/\sqrt{σ^2_p- σ^2_q})$ @rumathe